# Rare, seemingly random segmentation fault and read only memory error: Why? How do I fix?

Tags: julia, differential-equations, sundials

I'm trying to solve a system of DAE's in julia using sundials.jl. The original code works fine, but a monte carlo simulation for uncertainty quantification sometimes causes a segmentation fault.

```
`struct s_base
    s1::Float64
    s2::Float64
end


#DAE Tests
using DifferentialEquations
using Sundials

function f(out,du,u,p,t)
  out[1] = - p.s1*u[1]              + p.s2*u[2]*u[3] - du[1]
  out[2] = + p.s1*u[1] - 3e7*u[2]^2 - p.s2*u[2]*u[3] - du[2]
  out[3] = u[1] + u[2] + u[3] - 1.0
end

u₀ = [1.0, 0, 0]
du₀ = [-0.04, 0.04, 0.0]
tspan = (0.0,100000.0)


differential_vars = [true,true,false]


for n=1:1000000
    s=s_base(.04,1e4)
    prob = DAEProblem(f,du₀,u₀,tspan,s,differential_vars=differential_vars)
    sol = solve(prob,IDA())
end
`
```

I created the above toy example by modifying the dae example in the julia documentation to show the problem, but the incidence of error in the toy is lower than in the actual code (Though it still occurs).

Thanks for any help anyone might have!

Comment: Please file an issue to Sundials.jl

Comment: Is this example supposed to reproduce the segfault? Since I don't seem to get any segfaults when I run this locally, and I just ran it 10 times.

Comment: Interesting, I just reran it twice and it reproduced the segfault on my machine twice.

Comment: I should add that this example has been run on two computers, both running macOS, producing segfaults on both, and that the real code is segfaulting on a third computer running Linux.

Comment: Interesting, I am testing on Windows. How much RAM do you have? Curious if it's a GC thing

Comment: Both macs have 8 GB, the linux computer was using 2GB/core. I tried the toy on a windows computer with 32 GB of RAM and it didnt segfault, and I tried the real code on the same computer and it didnt segfault. I'm running on a Linux computer now with higher RAM to isolate the issue, will get back when I have results. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Bizarre. I'm trying to reproduce and will see what I get.

Comment: High memory on linux again resulted in segfault.

Comment: Yeah, we got a reproducing case, but only on Linux. Weird...

Comment: It looks like we can no longer recreate it... try again with the latest Julia? https://github.com/JuliaDiffEq/Sundials.jl/issues/218#issuecomment-522706742